# Media query problems wrong order?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have like 16 media queries or something and i noticed that if i put every media query portrait 1 different color some are falling under another media query. For instance i have:

`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {}`

and i have for instance:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and
 (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
and (orientation: portrait) {}
```

Then both backgrounds are red but i put the second background on purple. I am referring to my own website [www.gester.nl](http://gester.nl). Can someone help me and see into the website with media query code why some media queries are not working like they are supposed to work. Is it that i use a wrong order or something? I just use google f12 to see how it looks on other devices.

Comment: Both of these media queries are active between 320px and 480px

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries are overlapping. You will want to use something like the below to target specific screen sizes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
   // do stuff between 320px and 480px
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 568px) {
   // do stuff between 481px and 568px
}
```

Comment: Heey thanks for your answer, yeah it sounds logical if you say it like this but Oke i will try to do that. And i will let you know if it worked with all of them, Thanks!